# 2 way Socket communication over bluetooth

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

Is there any way to make communication with 2 RBI over bluetooth using python Socket?

Do you have some tips how I can do it? Should I use multithreading?

Right now I'm using this lib -> https://github.com/karulis/pybluez . So far I can create only one way communication: client-> server, but I would like to send response to the server too.

My goal is to setup up RFCOMM server and client who is searching for available RBi and communicate with it, on each RBI.

I would be very appriciate for any tips/suggestion.

The must have is: using python and bluetooth.

Thanks in advance!